# Rufus accidently used on a hard disk, now a whole raid box has been wiped

Tags: hard-drive, boot, raid, format, rufus

This is possibly a question for Akeo, the author of Rufus.

My problem is that I was using Rufus to format a USB drive, and I did something wrong. Now a whole ICY BOX RAID box (configured as RAID 5 internally with four disks), has been wiped off of hundreds of folders containing thousands of files.

This box is seen as one external HD through USB. Now the box has been split into two drives:

1. a small 494 kb disk with EFI folder and readme.txt
2. the second drive of 8TB with the boot, efi, sources, folders, and basic boot files (10 in all) and nothing else. PC indicates 8Tb of 8Tb free.

What do I do? An initial scan from EaseUS indicates none of the structure even after a deep scan.

Comment: There are some software solutions out there that are able to do partial recovery of RAID 5 volumes. However, I believe they require the drives to be directly attached to the PC instead of through a USB enclosure. Either way, it is unlikely that you will be able to recover all of your data, and you will have lost the folder structure of the original volume. Recovering any data will be a challenge. If the data is vital, and you have no other backups, you should send it to a professional for recovery, as any more work you do could result in irreversible data loss.

Comment: You should recover from backups.  You might be able to get fragments of your data back (with great effort and sucky results)  using something like recuva or photorec.  If you are vanishingly lucky, you might just be able to recover the partition data with testdisk, but the chanced of this are miniscule.

Comment: Not to add insult to injury, but this is a perfect example of 1) double or triple checking you are pointing to that right drive/volume when doing something destructive 2) disconnecting important drives/volumes to prevent accidental destruction and most importantly 3) have reliable, up-to-date, and recoverable backups.  The last option of number 3 is often overlooked.  I see so many people make backups incorrectly and then find out they cannot recover any data.  ***ALWAYS*** test restoring your data!

Comment: Yes, learnt some valuable life lessons in the last 3 weeks. Will try testdisk, recuva and photorec. Most of my files are video.

Answer (score 9):

Rufus author here. First of all, the proper channel to report issues is the [official issue tracker](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues).

I'm afraid however that there is not much I can do for you.

I literally went out of my way to ensure that large disks are not listed by default in Rufus and that, if you do want to have those listed, you must forcibly enable the hidden *"List USB Hard Drives"* option, which I will assume you had to enable to get that RAID drive listed. However, since Microsoft is really not helping with providing means to figure if a drive is a harmless external flash drive or your super important work backup drive, there's really [only so much I can do](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/blob/ba3665d990b2c11a59d0427547f28d2fc1101377/src/smart.c#L398-L440), and the onus remains on you to ensure that you are really formatting the drive you actually want to format.

So, as per [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Help_I_formatted_the_wrong_drive_by_mistake_How_do_I_recover_it) there's not much I can do for you here. Rufus will have overwritten the partition table altogether, so, unless you happen to have had a backup of that, you're pretty much screwed. One thing that may potentially help, if your drive was using GPT and was converted to MBR, is to look at the last 33 sectors of the drive as it may still contain a backup copy of the old GPT you were using, but, as other people advise, you will either have to restore from backups or consult a data recovery specialist.

Now, if it happens that Rufus was somehow listing your RAID drive by default (which, again, I can't be held responsible for, as I provide no guarantee that the HDD vs UFD detection algorithm used by Rufus, which I had to create from scratch, is 100% accurate, especially if your RAID controller reports your drive with the REMOVABLE attribute, or if you created a VHD on top of it), I am interested in your Rufus log which you can access with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> (you may also want to press pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> to turn on enumeration debugging) so that I can improve Rufus to avoid **others** running into the same problem.

But I'm afraid I don't have a solution to "fix" the formatting of your RAID drive, and you will have to either use your backups or consult a specialist.

Comment: Thank you. The RAID box still recognizes the RAID 5 setup, so I won't have to disassemble the disks individually to reconstruct the data, I assume.  The raid box was initialised in disk management as GPT disk. I did not change it to MBR. Also swapping the disk order does not affect the whole partition, does that mean it definately is GPT. I will somehow try and use data recovery software to look at the last 33 sectors.

Comment: If the RAID box was already GPT and Rufus created a GPT drive, then the backup GPT will have been overwritten as well. It's only if the RAID drive was GPT and your created an MBR drive in Rufus that you might have some hope at recovering the GPT (but then again, Rufus usually cleans up both the primary and backup GPT to avoid issues, so even then your hope of recovering the backup GPT is slim). I am still interested however in seeing your log with `Alt`-`.` (you don't need to create a drive or anything, just open Rufus, press `Alt`-`.` and send me your log).

Answer (score 0):

Akeo won't be able to help here, unfortunately.
Testdisk and Photorec may provide recovery.

After formatting the wrong partition I only perform dangerous operations on a separate laptop personnally.

Comment: Ok.I have been on it, recovered most of the files with correct data structure. Some files have been (lost) and recovered but cannot as yet play. Doing more recovery. Can anyone suggest a fast cloning disk software ? Mini tools partition master free has take 12 hours just to copy 3% of the 8TB. sector by sector. Thanks

Comment: I can only recommend GNU ddrescue, because that program has been designed to handle read errors and to circumvent them to avoid speed decreases when reaching error-containing regions of your drive. It runs under Linux.

Comment: thank you. Linux and ubuntu are new territories but at least it gives me options. I would send it for data recovery but for 8TB the costsd will be in Thousands for a few video files. I would say 80% recovered.

Comment: Compare those thousands to the price of a simple backup drive... 
I don't know what you mean by "I would say 80% recovered."
I am mostly using Microsoft legacy operating systems but for data recovery Linux is king.